# Transform Pyspark dataframe based on boolean value

Tags: pyspark, pivot

I have pyspark dataframe which is has only boolean values True and False

```
[Row(a=True, b=False, c=False, d=True, e=False, id=1, dummy='dummy'), 
 Row(a=False, b=False, c=True, d=True, e=False, id=2, dummy='dummy')]

+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+---+-----+
|    a|    b|    c|   d|    e| id|dummy|
+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+---+-----+
| true|false|false|true|false|  1|dummy|
|false|false| true|true|false|  2|dummy|
+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+---+-----+
```

I want to transform this table such way, it looks

```
[Row(id=1, True=['a', 'd'], False=['b','c','e']), 
 Row(id=2, True=['a', 'b', 'e'], False=['c','d'])]

+---+-----+----+
|id |false|true|
+---+-----+----+
|1  |b,c,e|a,d |
|2  |a,b,e|c,d |
+---+-----+----+
```

I have tried with Pivot, it is not helping. Could some one please suggest a way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to achieve it is to unpivot the data and then pivot the value field.

```
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('bool_struct_arr', 
               func.array(*[func.struct(func.lit(colnm).alias('name'), func.col(colnm).alias('val'))
                            for colnm, datatype in data_sdf.dtypes if datatype=='boolean']
                          )
               ). \
    selectExpr('id', 'inline(bool_struct_arr)'). \
    groupBy('id'). \
    pivot('val'). \
    agg(func.concat_ws(',', func.collect_list('name'))). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---+-----+----+
# |id |false|true|
# +---+-----+----+
# |1  |b,c,e|a,d |
# |2  |a,b,e|c,d |
# +---+-----+----+
```

The `bool_struct_arr` is an array of structs containing the column name (alias
`"name"`) and its value (alias `"val"`) as struct for all boolean columns available in the input dataframe (in this case `data_sdf`). The `inline` SQL function explodes the array of structs and creates new columns from the struct fields which can then be used in further aggregations.