# Splitting each Multi-Category columns to Multiple columns with counts

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

| date | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16-08-2022 | a | b | e |
| 16-08-2022 | a | b | f |
| 16-08-2022 | c | d | f |

output

| date | Value1_a | Value1_c | Value2_b | Value2_d | Value3_e | Value3_f |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16-08-2022 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |

continues like this for more columns maybe 10, I will aggregate on date and split the categorical columns with counts for each category , currently doing like this

```
spark.sql('select a.dateid,a.id,count(case when Value1="a" then 1 end) as value1_a,
count(case when Value1="b" then 1 end) as value1_b,
 from prep_data a group by a.dateid,a.id').show()
```

Need a good way to do this , any Python/Sql solution is fine .

Comment: you can use a similar approach to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73372264/8279585) and change the aggregation to `count()`

Comment: when i try this df. \
    withColumn('bool_struct_arr', 
               func.array(*[func.struct(func.lit(colnm).alias('name'), func.col(colnm).alias('val'))
                            for colnm in df.columns]
                          )
               ). \
    selectExpr('dateReceived', 'inline(bool_struct_arr)'). \
    groupBy('dateReceived'). \
    pivot('val'). \
    agg(func.count(func.collect_list('name'))). \
    show(truncate=False) AnalysisException: It is not allowed to use an aggregate function in the argument of another aggregate function.

Comment: the approach is similar - not exactly same. I've shared an answer on similar lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array of structs for the fields except the `date` field. Use `inline` to explode and create new columns, and then concatenate the field name and field value.

```python
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('val_struct_arr',
               func.array(*[func.struct(func.lit(k).alias('name'), func.col(k).alias('val')) 
                            for k in data_sdf.columns if k != 'dt']
                          )
               ). \
    selectExpr('dt', 'inline(val_struct_arr)'). \
    withColumn('name_val_concat', func.concat_ws('_', 'name', 'val')). \
    groupBy('dt'). \
    pivot('name_val_concat'). \
    count(). \
    fillna(0). \
    show()

# +----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
# |        dt|value1_a|value1_c|value2_b|value2_d|value3_e|value3_f|
# +----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
# |16-08-2022|       2|       1|       2|       1|       1|       2|
# +----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Thank you , I'm new to Pyspark and still learning , I did try one hot encoder in Pandas and tried to achieve this , but taking full advantage of parallel processing and learning/knowledge is what i was looking for , Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 =(data_sdf.withColumn('tab',F.array(*[F.struct(concat_ws('_',F.lit(k),col(k)).alias('var'), F.col(k).alias('val')) for k in data_sdf.columns if k != 'date']))#Create struct of columns and values
      .selectExpr('date','inline(tab)')#Convert df from wide to lon with one column for values
       .groupBy('date').pivot('var').agg(F.count('val')).show(truncate=False)#pivot
 )

+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|date      |Value1_a|Value1_c|Value2_b|Value2_d|Value3_e|Value3_f|
+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|16-08-2022|2       |1       |2       |1       |1       |2       |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```